# Filtrar varias palabras en python y devolver solo los strings que no contengan esas coincidencias

Tags: python-3.x

Muy buenas tardes a todos. He estado pensando en realizar un código en python que me permita filtrar ciertas frases recibidas, y que yo pueda escribir palabras que estén implícitas dentro de dichas frases y estas frases no se muestren en pantalla, sino solamente aquellas frases que no contienen esas palabras. Por ejemplo:

Tengo las siguientes frases:

```
TEST: NONE To test SGI:TATA-142 and TATA-453. 
TEST: TATA-432 Other test. In TATA-343 too. 
TEST:NONE New test. First TATA-12
modelos incompletos.
archivos estaticos creados.
```

y deseo filtrar por "NONE", "too" y "modelos", es decir, que solo debería visualizar:

```
archivos estáticos creados.
```

Para ello he pensado en un método que reciba dichas frases y que las palabras que deseo filtrar se almacenen dentro de una lista:

```py
def clean(frases):
    lista = ["NONE", "too", "modelos"]

    for value in lista:
        if value in frases:
            pass

        else:
            return frases
```

Esta es una vaga idea de lo que se me ha ocurrido en algunos intentos, ya que he probado, lo único que logro es que no retorne la frase con la ultima palabra almacenada en la lista, es decir, la palabra modelos "modelos" visualizando:

```
TEST: NONE To test SGI:TATA-142 and TATA-453. 
TEST: TATA-432 Other test. In TATA-343 too. 
TEST:NONE New test. First TATA-12
archivos estaticos creados.
```

También he probado utilizando el método `find()` de python, pero en todos mis ensayos obtengo el mismo resultado, cuando intento realizar dicho proceso para mas de una palabra. Me gustaría saber si alguno de ustedes conoce alguna forma o alguna palabra reservada en python que me pueda ayudar con mi tarea. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios errores lógicos en el planteamiento, por dos razones:

1. No construyes nunca una nueva lista con los valores "correctos", sino que tu función retorna `frases`, que es la misma lista que recibiste. De modo que nunca eliminará nada (no me explico cómo es que dices que en el resultado eliminó una frase)
2. Para mirar si una palabra está en alguna de las frases pones: `if value in frases` pero esto no funcionará como esperas. Esto sólo mira si `value` (que será por ejemplo la palabra `"NONE"` es uno de los elementos de la lista `frases`, pero no lo será, ya que esa lista contiene cadenas largas. Ninguna de esas cadenas es `"NONE"` aunque puede **contener** `"NONE"`.

   En definitiva, que tendrías que iterar para cada frase y mirar si la palabra está en esa frase, con algo como:

   ```
   for value in lista:
       for frase in frases:
           if value in frase:
               ...
   ```
3. Lo que debes hacer en caso  de que se cumpla, es saltarte esa frase (eso lo hacías bien), pero en caso de que no se cumpla debes **añadir** esa frase a otra lista que contendrá el resultado a retornar. Y no retornar nada aún. El `return` estará fuera de estos bucles.
4. En realidad lo anterior tampoco sería correcto, pues ¿qué pasa si la palabra "NONE" está en una frase, pero la palabra "too" no está? Ya que vamos iterando por `values`, si encontramos que uno de los `values` no está en la frase, la damos por buena. Pero más adelante podríamos encontrar (en otra iteración) que otra palabra sí que está, por lo que no tendríamos que haberla dado por buena antes.

   La solución a esto es, en primer lugar, invertir los bucles. Iterar antes por las frases. Y para cada frase decidir si la conservamos o no mirando si *alguna* de las palabras aparece en ella. Sólo si ninguna aparece debe conservarse.

Es decir, tomando la misma idea que pretendías expresar en tu código, pero corrigiendo estos problemas, sería así:

```
def clean(frases):
    lista = ["NONE", "too", "modelos"]
    resultado = []

    for frase in frases:
        conservar = True
        for palabra in lista:
            if palabra in frase:
                conservar = False
        if conservar:
            resultado.append(frase)
    return resultado
```

Lo anterior sería una versión "simple" que usa tan solo bucles y características bien conocidas del lenguaje. Usando programación funcional puede simplificarse mucho, como muestra la respuesta de Adrián Sanz.

Comment: Hola, entiendo lo que me quieres decir, la verdad si me encontraba demasiado perdido, y como mencione en la publicación, era una idea vaga de lo que quería hacer, pero ya comprendo mejor como  encontrar la solución mas optima. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Depende un poco de cómo tengas almacenadas las frases, suponiendo que las tengas en una lista podría valerte lo siguiente tal y como lo he puesto, si lo tuvieses de otra forma tendrías que adaptarlo un poco.

Puedes utilizar `not in` que hace lo contrario que `in` y `all()`, así cuando todos 'no estén' los incluirá en tu resultado:

```
frases = ['TEST: NONE To test SGI:TATA-142 and TATA-453.',
          'TEST: TATA-432 Other test. In TATA-343 too.',
          'TEST:NONE New test. First TATA-12',
          'modelos incompletos.',
          'archivos estaticos creados.']

lista = ["NONE", "too", "modelos"]


def clean(frases):
    return [frase for frase in frases if all(map(lambda x:x not in frase, lista))]

print(clean(frases))
```

Esto te devolvería solamente `['archivos estaticos creados.']`

Comment: Hola, las frases me llegan como cadenas de texto, una tras otra, no se si me hago entender, pero tu ejemplo me es de mucha ayuda para organizar mi código. Muchas gracias.